# About save string inside an array

Tags: matlab

I have question about how can I get from a user multiple inputs(once per line) as a string and save it inside an array ?

I tried something like this :

```
function[str] = get_data()

st = '';

st{1} = input{'enter the first name','s'};
st{2} = input{'enter the first name','s'};

str = strings(st)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your cell beforehand as a cell. Not as a string. Then you can fill it with the inputs.

```
function[str] = get_data()

st = cell(1,2);
st{1} = input('enter the first name','s');
st{2} = input('enter the last name','s');
str=[st{:}] %if you want to convert it back to a string
%str = strcat(st{1},'_',st{2}) %if you want a _ between the inputs

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
st = [];
st{1} = input('enter the first name: ','s');
st{2} = input('enter the last name: ','s');
str = strcat(st{1},'_',st{2})
```